# Can I cache an empty form template as a second page in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, caching

can I cache an empty form template as a second page in browser cache 
so that when you click "create event" button on first page it immediately 
opens empty  form template without having a need to download the template 
from the server as it's cached.

Just like CREATE EVENT button in Google calendar; which let's you to switch between calendar and new event form template.

Comment: The way Google does it in the calendar app is a hidden element that is shown upon click, at the same time it will hide the main content element, as far as caching the form based on the way you're describing it, anything is possible possible but I wouldn't want to be the one writing the script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can either use Javascript for building the new page from scratch when the respective action is invoked (probably quite tedious) or you can use an invisible section (e.g., a separate `<div>`) of the HTML page (style = `display: none`) and make it visible by changing its class to a visible style and making the original page invisible (change its style to `display: none`).

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be to load your second view into a hidden container.  You can hide it with a simple CSS display property toggle, like this:

```
<div id="mySecondView" style="display: none;">
  <!-- content of second view here -->
</div>
```

And on button click you can do this to unhide it:

With jQuery:

```
$('#mySecondView').show();
```

or

```
$('#mySecondView').fadeIn();
```

Without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('mySecondView').style.display = '';
```

Of course you'll have to position the second view via CSS as you want it, otherwise it'll just pop up in some weird place that won't make sense.